# Is there any way to preview the size of an rsync transfer?

Tags: rsync

I'm working on a wrapper around `rsync`, and one of the points would be to determine whether the destination has enough space to accommodate the transfer; as a result, I'd like to know the size of the transfer so that I can compare it against the output of `du`.

I know about [using `rsync` to generate lists of changed files](https://serverfault.com/questions/618735/can-i-use-rsync-to-create-a-list-of-only-changed-files#618740), but considering potentially huge file lists as well as the necessity of parsing the output of that `rsync` invocation, and the overhead of crawling that file list while running `diff` on every file and then computing the difference, I'd like to know if there are native (or even just better) ways of doing this.

Comment: It's not definitive, but you can try `rsync --dry-run --stats`?

Comment: not of the transfer, but of the final size? A shortcut would be to compute the local size, assuming you're using something like --delete to keep them completely in sync.

Comment: @DopeGhoti That'll do it!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It will not show the size of partial transfers, but you can get a general feel for the total size of the data set by adding the `--dry-run` and `--stats` switches to `rsync`.  It doesn't test the far side of the operation to see just how much data is changed, but will at least show you the size of all files that *may* be synchronized.